# Application insights dashboard pie chart doesnt work as expected

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, dashboard

```
| where client_Type != "Browser"
| summarize count() by toint(resultCode)
| extend iff(toint(resultCode)<500,'pass','fail')
| render piechart
```

This simple query doesnt work as expected, i'm expecting piechart with two slices...one for fail and another one for pass. But results are weird

[image]

[image]

Comment: you mean the failed/pass percentage are not correct?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, thats the problem.

Comment: In your query, in the `summarize` line, since you convert the resultCode  to int type, then in the pie chart, it will calculate the 500/(200+304+204+500+400+404) as failed percentage(24.85%). Please see the answer below:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your query like below:

```
requests 
| extend passOrNot=iff(toint(resultCode)<500,'pass','fail')
| summarize count() by passOrNot, resultCode
| render piechart
```

The test result:

[image]

[image]